# Not able to create 'reportviewer' Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2022

In beginning 'reportviewer' was not showing in toolbox than i installed "Microsoft RDLC Report Designer" from this link "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001"  then I got reportviewer in toolbox but now when I want to add reportviewer to the form but it shows this error the moment I drag and drop the report viewer from toolbox to form.

Comment: The very page you link to says the 2022 version is [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio2022)

Answer (score 0):

The report viewer does not come with the designer but is a NuGet package you can add on.

Right click on you project (or solution) and select Manage NuGet Packages.

Install the package for the type of project you creating, for example:

Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WinForms

etc...